# How to get fold expr working with terminal in vim 8

Tags: vim

I wrote my function *myfold* to handle folding command outputs in vim terminal called with `:terminal`. I set `foldmethod=expr` and `foldexpr=_myfold_()`.

If I copy the lines from my terminal buffer to a regular buffer, it works. But, if I try it directly in vim terminal I cannot use fold, I get *E490* error.

I checked *foldmethod* and *fold_expr* and the values are correct. What did I miss?

Comment: Does this work with a minimal, primitive foldexpr? (I tested it; it works for me.) If so, please divide-and-conquer yours to find the problematic part. Also, the terminal support is quite new, what's exact your Vim `:version`?

Comment: I did try with a minimal version and it did not work. Since it works for you, I will check if the problem is from my _vimrc_.

Comment: I tried with an empty _vimrc_ and it did not work either. My version is 8.1.